# How to get latitude and longitude from a mark in the map

Tags: java, android

I use this function **getLocation** to get the latitude and longitude from device. But what I am looking for is a way to use a mark, position it in the map **mapView** and get the latitude and longitude of it. Is there an example of it?

One way would be a mark in the center of the map, and move the map until the mark is in the desired position of the map, and read the longitude and latitude of the mark

```
public void getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            //return TODO;
                        }
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitud = location.getLatitude();
                            longitud = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //get the location by gps
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitud = location.getLatitude();
                                longitud = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the mark added by your app at some time, or you want Some Object that originally exist in the map? If later, your question should change to : how to get the Object at that place when I click a latitude + longtitude on the map?

Comment: thanks but how can I get the coordinate of the map's center?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is just to listen the event when the user touch the mapView

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
               
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                        .title("Location touched");    
            }
        }
    });
```

This will create a marker every time, in case you want to remplace it, just clear the other markers before adding another one.

Comment: Thanks but the event setOn;apClickListener is not in the MapViewLite class

Comment: You didn't mention that, so there was no way on knowing that. Be specific if you have more conditions on the answer. Also from documentation: `Lite mode supports GoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener() and GoogleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener().`